# Affine subspace $V\subseteq S(n)$ invariant under group action $x\mapsto gxg^{\mathrm{T}}$ of $G\subseteq GL(n, \mathbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, lie-groups

Given an affine subspace $V\subseteq S(n)$, where $S(n)$ is the real symmetric $n\times n$ matrices, is there a neat characterization of the maximal subgroup $G\subseteq GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ (with the group operation of left multiplication) such that $V$ is invariant (as a set) under the action $x\mapsto gxg^{\mathrm{T}}$ of $G$?

I took the very basic case of $n = 2$ and played around with some such subspaces and solved for the elements of $G$ by hand, and nothing really popped out at me, but I wonder if there's anything general we can say about $G$ if we have a parametrization of $V$, e.g. $$V = \left\{M_0+\sum_{i=1}^m t_iM_i : (t_1, \ldots, t_m)\in \mathbb{R}^m\right\}$$ for some $M_0, \ldots, M_m\in S(n)$.

Thanks for everyone's insights!

Comment: I realized I should have specified $V$ as an affine subspace of $S(n)$ (real symmetric $n\times n$ matrices) instead of just $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Answer (score 0):

The action is a similarity transformation and hence a rotation and scale. You are taking an affine subspace of S(n) and asking what the maximum similarity transformation group is.

Let $v \in V$ so that $v = s + t$ where $s,t \in S(n)$ then $g \in GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ is matrix multiplication: $w = gvg^T = gsg^T + gtg^T$ and you're asking what is the largest subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ that will give $w \in V$.

Clearly then $gtg^T = t$ since else we will end up in a different affine subspace. So $gt = tg$ or $[g,t] = 0$. Furthermore, once this is established $gsg^T$ must be in the translated kernel of $G$.

Essentially $V = g(V - t)g^T + t = gVg^T - gtg^T + t$. G must leave t and V fixed. There is only one fixed point in a similarity transform and that is the origin.

The problem is that $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ will not be able to capture this since you need to be able to represent an affine transformation. This require V to be at least a proper subspace. From this, you just take the subgroup of $GL(n-1,\mathbb{R})$ and then add in the affine translation component. Invertability is not changed.

The problem is really no different the non-affine case but one has to go down in dimension. Most likely the treason you had issues with dimension 2 is end up with scalars as you need to $GL(n+1,\mathbb{R})$ to compensate for the affine component.

A very simple way to think about this is that affine vector spaces are simply non-affine vector spaces in one extra dimension(by adding a dimension the translation component of "affineness" becomes just a standard vector component and we can ignore the difference).

Comment: It's not clear to me that we need $gtg^{\mathrm{T}} = t$, merely that $gtg^{\mathrm{T}}\in V$. Here's an example that I did on the $2\times 2$ matrices: consider the affine subspace $V$ consisting of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} x & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then, the maximal subgroup $G$ under which $V$ is invariant consists of elements of the form $$\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \pm 1-\alpha \\ 0 & \pm 1\end{pmatrix}$$ for $\alpha\neq 0$.

Comment: Note in that above example that $$\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 1-\alpha \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0 \\ 1-\alpha & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha^2(x-1)+1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ which is not equal to $\begin{pmatrix} x & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ unless $x = 1$ or $\alpha^2 = 1$.

Comment: @BrockA. Yes, and x cannot = 1 because then V is reduced to a point. a cannot be -1 because you end up with a different space. Hence a must be 1. This gives the identity matrix and so G consists of only the identity and so $gtg^T = t$. It's not that $gtg^T$ has to equal $t$, but suppose it is not $s = gtg^T$ and so $t = g^Tsg$. But you can then simply find another element $h \in G$ and repeat the process and you can choose $h$ to be $g^T$ which will map $s$ to $t$. It's a little hard to write out but it all will work out because the "translation component" is the same no matter what.

Comment: Think about it more like this: Extend to 3D.  You do this by adding an extra row and column. The row will end in 1 and the column will have the 2D translation vector. Then when you go to find $G \in GL(3, \mathbb{R})$ you will have a row with $<0,0,1>$ and as you expand through the action nothing will ultimately change. The translation vector will carry through the entire process and remain unchanged. Just extend V to 3D, extend G to 3D and it will be entirely the same math.

Comment: $V = \begin{pmatrix}
x & 1 & a\\
1 & 1 & b\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$,

$g = \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & 1-\alpha & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

then $V = gVg^T$. But note we are not dealing with an affine space here, just looking for a subgroup of GL that keep V invariant(I'm not saying here that g is maximal though). By going to a dimension one hire we can ignore the "affineness" aspects.

Comment: I still don't see why this extension is necessary when we already had $gVg^{\mathrm{T}}\subseteq V$ for $$V = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} x & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} : x\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$ and the subgroup $$g = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \pm 1-\alpha \\ 0 & \pm 1\end{pmatrix} : \alpha\neq 0\right\}$$ This would seem to be exactly the definition of an [invariant subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace). Is there some reason why we should require every point of $V$ to have a nontrivial orbit?

Comment: @BrockA. There is a difference between an invariant sub-$vector$-space and an invariant sub-$affine$-space. So it is not enough to simply treat $V$ as a vector space. For V' to be a sub-$affine$-space of $V$ it has to have the same translation relationship that V has. If you change that translation you get an isomorphic vector space but they are different affine spaces and $V' \neq V$. They are identical as vectors paces but not as affine spaces. So by requiring that $gtg^T \in V$ rather than $gtg^T = t$ you get an isomorphic vector space but not an invariant affine space.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. In light of your comments, and because I didn't realize that invariance of affine spaces was a stronger property than invariance of sets, I've updated the question to read how I actually intended, which is to say that $V$ should be invariant *as a set* under the group action of $G$.

Comment: @BrockA. then your method should be valid. In this case we just need gVg^T = V. You are then just asking about invariance under G of a vector space. In this case the translation component is irrelevant. Let $G = \{g \in GL(n,\mathbb{R}) | gvg^t \in V\; \forall v \in V\}$. This is the maximum subspace of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ of linear maps from $V \rightarrow V$ with the similarity property.

Comment: @BrockA. Also, just in case you don't know, you are talking about the centralizer $C_G(V)$.

Comment: I know what the centralizer $C_G(S) = \{x\in G : xs = sx \forall s\in S\}$ is for $S$ a subgroup of $G$, but here you are talking about the centralizer for $S$ a submanifold of a manifold on which we have an action from $G$. How is this defined?

Comment: @BrockA. V is a vector space and GL(n,R) is a vector space of dimension n^2 of which V is a subspace of it. Specially you are talking about the orthogonal group but it all works out to be the same idea. $xs = sx$ is the same as $x = sxs^{-1}$ but in O(n,R) it is $sxs^T = x$. If you want it to be isomorphically invariant then you use the Normalizer.

Comment: $V$ does not contain the origin, if we are talking about the same $V$ from the problem, and neither does $GL(n)$ (unless our vector space operation is something other than addition). Even if we consider $V$ without its translation, $S(n)$ contains noninvertible elements not in $GL(n)$.